# JAX-RS 2.1: JSON-B adapter applied when unexpected

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, payara, jsonb-api

### Problem:

Given the REST endpoint:

```java
@Path("/companies")
@Stateless
public class CompanyService{

    @EJB
    private CompanyEjb ejb;

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Company update(Company company){
        return ejb.update(company);
    }

}
```

After submitting a `PUT` request, JAX-RS is expected to return the updated company such as

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Company",
    "departments": [1,2]
}
```

However, only the primary key, `1`, is returned. A second request triggers an exception:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[[RestApplicationClass]: Servlet.service() for servlet RestApplicationClass threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Long.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.ReflectionUtils.lambda$createNoArgConstructorInstance$1(ReflectionUtils.java:188)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.ReflectionUtils.createNoArgConstructorInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectDeserializer.getInstance(ObjectDeserializer.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AdaptedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(AdaptedObjectDeserializer.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserializeItem(Unmarshaller.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserialize(Unmarshaller.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.deserialize(JsonBinding.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.fromJson(JsonBinding.java:85)
```

The adapter seems to be applied altough I don't have the company to be adapted

### Context

Configuration is:

- Payara 5.0.0.Alpha3 (hence Yasson 1.0)
- Java EE 8 (hence JAX-RS 2.1, JSON-B 1.0 a JSON-P 1.1)
- Application is packed in EAR format
- REST request submitted with Postman

Two entities `Company` and `Department` are linked by a `@OneToMany` relationships. Both entities have a primary key `id` and a name `name`. To avoid JSON infinite loop, the `@ManyToOne` Company of Department has an adapter:

```java
public class Department{
    // ...
    @ManyToOne // JPA stuff irrelevant here
    @JsonbTypeAdapter(CompanyAdapter.class)
    private Company company;
    // ...
}
```

with the (simplified) adapter:

```java
public class CompanyAdapter implements JsonbAdapter<Company, Long>{

    @EJB
    private CompanyEjb ejb;

    @Override
    public Long adaptToJson(Company orgnl) throws Exception {
        return orgnl != null ? orgnl.getId() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public E adaptFromJson(Long adptd) throws Exception {
        return ejb.findById(adptd);
    }
}
```

### Workaround:

Initially, I thought that once an adapter is defined, they will be applied everywhere, similarly to JPA Converters with `autoApply = true`. This led me nowhere

At first, I thought about using the last version of Yasson (1.0.2-SNAPSHOT) to fix the problem. To do so, I need to tell Payara to load the Yasson I want. So the `glassfish-web.xml` is modified as followed:

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    ...
    <!-- <class-loader delegate="true"/> -->
    <class-loader delegate="false"/>
    ...
</glassfish-web-app>
```

<sub>according to [Payara documentation](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/documentation/extended-documentation/classloading.html).</sub>

But it appears than only switching the `class-loader` delegation to false is enough.

**=> why?**

### Subsidiary question:

Because of some [hot-deploy](https://github.com/eclipse/yasson/issues/76) issues, I need to do the following to test my changes:

1. make the changes
2. build & deploy
3. restart the server after deploy

If by any chance someone knows why a hot-deploy/simple deploy modifies the JAX-RS adapter behaviour, I'm looking forward the answer

Answer (score 1):

Just to post back to SO here, the OP raised a detailed [GitHub issue](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson/issues/76) on Yasson and the root cause is that Yasson caches the object model (so it doesn't have to re-scan object models every time).  This caching causes issue in an application server environment where Yasson is provided by the container (e.g. JAX-RS runtime) and when the user updates their app, only their app classes get reloaded but Yasson and it's caches remain loaded.

### Short term fix

The workaround for now is to restart the app server when making changes to your JSON-B data classes.

### Long term

[I'm going to see](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson/issues/76#issuecomment-445911735) if Yasson and/or JSON-B spec can define some sort of "clear caches" hook. The idea here would be when an app server hot-updates an app, it can invoke this "clear cache" hook to flush out the stored object model from the application.